# ArgoCD helm chart how to override values yml in declarative helm chart deployment App/controller

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, argocd, gitops

I have an yaml which gets deployed by the ArgoCd controller, that deploys a helm chart from artifactory.

For my local development I use a sperate values.yml in the helm chart.

My controller looks like below [refer git link](https://github.com/argoproj/applicationset/issues/173)

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: <name-to-the-app>
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  project: default
  source:
    repoURL: https://harbor.1000kit.org/chartrepo/1000kit/
    targetRevision: <version-hardcode-in-repo>
    chart: <chart-name-that-is-getting-deployed>
    helm:
       releaseName: <release-name-hardcoded>
       # custom values to override the helm chart one
       values: |
          <pass-the-custom-values>>
  destination:
        server: https://kubernetes.default.svc
        namespace: <namespace-where-to-be-deployed>
  syncPolicy:
        automated:
          prune: true
          selfHeal: true
```

- The helm chart that is getting deployed is containing the values.yaml
- I am trying to override the values.yml present in the helm chart in artifcatory, so passing all the values in part of the source -> helm -> values like above.

Question:

- In the custom values, I skipped some value but the ArgoCd is fetching those values from the helm chart value.yml and using it. Is this the behavior?

Another observation is that, The helm chart repo values.yaml is being loaded as parmater in the ArgoCD, and the `argocd.io application` yaml the values are displayed in the UI.

From the documents i see there are parameters, which can be overridden but the values can't be overridden.

```
  spec:
    source:
      helm:
        parameters:
        - name: app
          value: $ARGOCD_APP_NAME
```

Is there any option to explicitly tell ArgoCD to ignore the values.yml from the helm chart in artifactory.

I am new to ArgoCd

Comment: similar to this issue https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/issues/9175

Answer (score 0):

Looks like,

The helm chart in the artifactory has a key : value combination say

```yaml
# value present in the helm chart values.yaml 
app-details: 
   name: "demoapp"
   version: "1.0"
   description: "simple demo app"
```

In argoCd `application` manifest

```yaml
# .....
  helm:
       releaseName: <release-name-hardcoded>
       # custom values to override the helm chart one
       values: |
          app-details : 
             name: "demoapp"
             version: "1.0"
             # if I didn't specify the description here <--------------- *
# ....
```

`*` - ArgoCd is setting the default value (from values.yaml) for  description key in this case. This description value can be seen in the deployed manifest.

Also the values.yml data are displayed as parameter in the UI.

I had to use a different approach, where I need to make changes in the template charts that uses this description value.